# What could cause askubuntu to be displayed wrongly?

Tags: firefox, kde, fonts

On my main machine, I installed some fonts manually, by copying them to `/usr/local/share/fonts/` amd then running `sudo fc-cache -fv` as sudgested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts/3701#3701) answer. Now some askubuntu sites look like this:

[image]

and I cannot see the posts I write.
Are the two events related? Or, how can I arrive at the bottom of this? Using another Firefox profile on the same machine, does give me the same problem.**Using chrome however does not**.

[image]

I have tried clearing the cache in the browser. I also reinstalled fonts by running:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/share/fonts/truetype | cut -sd: -f1 | tr -d ,)
```

as suggested in an answer to [this](http://Reinstall%20default%20truetype%20fonts%20(Ubuntu%2016.04)) question.

Comment: can you post the list of fonts returned by this command `fc-list`

Comment: @bistoco That is a rather long list...735 lines. How should I add that without making the qquestion unreadable? Or, what am I looking for?

Comment: This are the fonts that the page uses for the code blocks `Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif`.

Comment: Ok,  Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console,monospace,sans-serif are not in the output of fc-list. Does this mean I uninstalled them for some reason? BTW in chrome the site is displayed properly./ Where can I find those fonts?

Comment: [this may help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942311/reinstall-default-truetype-fonts-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @bistoco Thank you. I tried Oli's solution from the Question you linked to, to no avail. I also am a bit confused as google chrome renders the page correctly (though I am not very savvy with this kind of system administration).

Comment: @bistoco Sorry for pinging you, but is there a way to see which packages would provide Menlo, Monaco and Lucida?

Comment: Is that FF57? I had [problems too](http://alicious.com/firefox-57-font-missing/ "description of fixing FF font problem") with it. There was a bug, I think it's fixed in 57.0.1. This [bug page](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418240) has more details. IIRC I had to clean up the directories my fonts were in as they were in unusual places and the sandboxing was thus interfering with them.

Comment: ..@pbhj This is FF 57.0.1. Though it might have been 57 when the problem first occured. I will look into the suggested workaround, but this is highly promissing.

Comment: @pbhj Please add "Going to about:preferences > Language & Appearance > Advanced, and unsettin "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" resolves the issue " as an answer. This is a workaround not compromising security and potentially helping even in cases of other future bugs and should therefore be included as an answer.

Comment: @Bruni it's added as an answer to the marked duplicate; add it here yourself if you wish though.